# What does it mean that Mercurial stores branch information as a permanent part of each commit?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

My understanding is that **Git** is sort of a linked list when each node is a self-sufficient object that has all information about the commit such as differences between current and previous commits.

I thought that **Mercurial** is also sort of a linked list. But, then I read that mercurial stores branch information as a permanent part of each commit and therefore branches cannot be removed

What does that mean "cannot be removed"? How the commits are stored then, like a huge one node?

Comment: Mercurial also stores commits in a DAC, it simply has a text field storing a branch name for each changeset. Mercurial tags and bookmarks are more like git branches. I don't think git has anything quite like hg branches.

Comment: Mercurial stores changesets (not snapshots) in an append-only log-like database. A changeset data structure has pre-allocated fields: two 256-byte parent commit hash ID slots, for instance, and a branch name slot. To remove commits (`hg strip`), Mercurial has to rewrite the append-only log. The data for each changeset are complex as files are normally stored as deltas but occasionally there's a "reset" and a new copy of the file.

Comment: Git, meanwhile, has an "objects database" indexed by hash ID, with four "object types". Objects themselves are stored either "loose" (zlib-compressed but nothing else) or "packed" (delta-compressed against other objects in the same pack file), with the deepest compression magic being in the pack-file builders. This is a very different view of the world. Commit objects, one of the four types, store only commit metadata, relying on additional objects to store a "tree" (snapshot).

Comment: (oops, I meant 256-*bit* not 256-*byte*.)

Comment: @torek that all sounds like a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Both Git and HG use DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) topology, which is **not** just "linked list"
2. Yes, in core Mercurial (not in evolve extension in game) existing branches can't be removed (see `hg help branch`), but **it's nohow related** to *storing additional metadata* (branch-name) in changeset